# Name of this Kronecker-product-like operation?

Tags: matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

Suppose $A,B$ are $n$-by-$m$ matrices. Let $X_i$ indicate i'th column of matrix $X$, $\otimes$ indicate Kronecker product.

I'm interested in $n^2$-by-$m$ matrix $C$ where

$c_i = a_i \otimes b_i$

Is there a name for this operation, or a way to express it in terms of conventional math operations?

Comment: This is sometimes called the Khatri-Rao product. See the intro of Kolda's siam review paper on tensor decompositions and applications. Beware though, sometimes people use this name to refer to something different.

Comment: This is useful in dealing with tensors that have been unfolded into matrices. Section 2.6 in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.454.202&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks, those equations look quite useful! This came up when I tried to get expression for covariance matrix of gradients for when doing SGD to solve least squares linear regression with vector-valued Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually called the Khatri-Rao product. Beware though, sometimes sources (including parts of wikipedia) use the same name to refer to something different.

It often arises when dealing with tensors that have been flattened into matrices.

For a reference, see section 2.6 of the following paper:

> Kolda, Tamara G., and Brett W. Bader. "Tensor decompositions and
>   applications." SIAM review 51.3 (2009): 455-500. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.454.202&rep=rep1&type=pdf

In the paper they list some algebraic properties of the Khatri-Rao product, which I repeat here for reference.

Let $\odot$ be the Khatri-Rao product as defined in this question and $*$ be the Hadamard (entrywise multiplication) product. I.e., writing $\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ as the column vectors of $A$ and $B$ respectively, we define
\begin{align}
A \odot B :=& \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{a}_1 \otimes \mathbf{b}_1 & \mathbf{a}_2 \otimes \mathbf{b}_2 & \dots & \mathbf{a}_n \otimes \mathbf{b}_n\end{bmatrix}, \\
(A * B)_{ij} :=& A_{ij} B_{ij}.
\end{align}
Also let $M^\dagger$ denote the pseoduinverse of $M$. Then the following algebraic identities hold:
\begin{align}
A \odot B \odot C &= (A \odot B) \odot C = A \odot (B \odot C)\\
(A \odot B)^T(A \odot B) &= A^T A * B^TB \\
(A \odot B)^\dagger &= ((A^T A)*(B^T B))^\dagger (A \odot B)^T
\end{align}

Comment: Is the first of the three identities at the end of your post correct? I would have thought that $(A\odot B)\odot C = A\odot (B\odot C)$

Comment: @Ziofil Good catch, thanks. Fixed.